# get user from form builder symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony

I want to retrieve the list of the frames of a current company in a select form, Knowing that the current user is a company.

But I had the following error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class "Gestion\StageBundle\Form\StageType".
>
> Did you mean to call e.g. "getBlockPrefix", "getName" or "getParent"?

**my classType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $ent_id= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $builder->add('sujet')->add('dateDebut')->add('dateFin')
    ->add('encadreur', EntityType::class, array(

    'class' => 'UserBundle:Encadreur',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.entreprise=$ent_id')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },

    'choice_label' => 'username',

    ));
}
```

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Comment: You need to post whole your code here to make us know where did you inject service container. I think that you did it wrong. And also it is a bad practice to inject whole container in every class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add TokenStorage to your form Type constructor

```
private $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}
```

and make your form Type as service e.g.

```
app.form.something:
        class: Gestion\StageBundle\Form\StageType
        arguments: ['@security.token_storage']
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

and then you can get user in form Type

```
$user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
```